# Змейка c# , изменение направления

Tags: c#, консоль

```
public void ChangeDirection(object state)
{
    while (true)
    {
        while (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        lock (state)
        {
            switch (key.Key)
            {
                 //
            }
        }
     }
```

Тут реализована смена направления у змейки.

Работает так: если змейка движется направо, то она может изменить направления в любую сторону, но не влево (то есть задним ходом змейка не сдаст). Все работает, кроме одного но, если  нажимать быстро, например, вверх-влево, то в этой же строчке она изменит свое направление на противоположенное(запрещенное влево).

Как мне казалось проблема в очистки буфера консоли

```
while (Console.KeyAvailable)
{
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

На просторах нашел такой способ его очистки, но, видимо, не работает.

Подскажи те, пожалуйста, где ошибка или что я делаю не так?
И Можно ли как то получить очередь нажатых клавиш?

единственный ввод у меня в этом методе (метод отностится к классу Snake), вызывается он в потоке

```
Snake snake = new Snake(); 
object obj = new object();  
Thread keyboard = new Thread(snake.ChangeDirection);  // Смена   направления.метод, который рассматривается с самого начала
keyboard.Start(obj);
while (true)
{
     lock (obj)
     { 
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        snake.Movement(obj); // перемещение координат ,switch с увелечением X или Y
     } 
     snake.Draw(); 
 }
```

P.S. На другом ПК работает все четко...

Comment: ошибка скорее не в очистке консоли, а в способе обработки ввода пользователя. Покажите основной цикл программы без лишних деталей разумеется

Comment: @rdorn добавил в вопрос

Comment: тогда я бы сделал так. Две переменные направления. Одна для змейки, вторая для клавиатуры. Перед очередным перемещением змейки, проверяем, допустимо ли новое значение направления, если да - меняем, если нет - игнорируем

Comment: @rdorn такая проверка существует внутри метода смены направления.  И она работает, но проблема в немного в другом.
предположим она направление у нас вправо. если я нажму влево , то все отработает как положено и ничего не произойдет, но если я нажму вверх/вниз и сразу же влево, то не изменяя строчки , она пойдет влево. Надеюсь объяснил

Comment: правильно, точнее не правильно =), проверка должна быть не в методе смены направления, там пользователь пусть что хочет творит, а в методе движения змейки, которой критично новое направление

Comment: @rdorn спасибо, попробую сейчас переделать)

Comment: Могу оформить ответом?

Comment: да , конечно, думаю именно в этом проблема и была

Comment: @MikhailZnak, а можно взглянуть на вашу консольную змейку? Я просто пару лет назад писал тоже змейку, но в winforms и была такая же проблема, но я ее решил. Как уже не помню, но по-моему там было что-то вроде двух переменных, одна из которых действующее направление движения, вторая - следующее направление движения. Если пользователь нажал кнопку, то проверяется, может ли змейка туда пойти, если нет, то сохраняет прежнее направление. И собственно, в тот тайминг, который есть у пользователя перед следующим шагом змейки, он может пустить ее в любом направлении кроме обратного.

Comment: @Oleg Klezovich пока не готова, только движение сделал, но как будет, то могу скинуть

Comment: @MikhailZnak очень интересно посмотреть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По итогам диалога в комментариях:

Главным действующим элементом в данном случае является "змейка", именно она знает, какое направление для нее допустимо а какое нет. Поэтому и проверку на допустимость нового направления, нужно делать в методе движения "змейки", а пользователь может вводить что угодно, нам просто нужно знать что было введено перед очередным движением. Соответственно - действия пользователя, без проверок складываем в буферную переменную, и перед очередным перемещением проверяем: новое направление допустимо - меняем направление и движемся, недопустимо - игнорируем и движемся в предыдущем направлении.

---

Подобная схема позволяет реализовать все возможные модификации поведения "змейки" при попытке изменить направление на противоположное, которые встречались в истории этой игры:

- реверс, голова и хвост меняются местами без паузы.
- остановка, встречается в облегченном варианте оригинала.
- смерть, встречается в хардкорных вариантах, рассматривается как столкновение с хвостом.